# Help with window.history.pushState

Tags: jquery, pushstate

I need help with syntax.

My site loads blog posts within the #board div using AJAX and I close it by clicking #close. When I load a post the url becomes like this http://www.visualise.ca/#!/anne-au-cherry and I would like to come back to http://www.visualise.ca/ when I close the post. The following gives me http://www.visualise.ca/#/

```
$("#close").live("click", function(event) {
    $("#board").slideUp("slow");
    window.location.hash = "#/";
    window.history.pushState(null,null,site_url+"/");
    return false;
});
```

1) Can someone help please ?

2) What if the browser doesn't support html5 ?

Many thanks for your time and help.

**UPDATE: THIS WORKS, there was a typo in my 'site_url' variable.**

Answer (score 4):

PushState is not operation over the hash. If you want it to be < html5 compatible you need to use hash.

pushState is changing the url without changing page:

If you see the history as an array, `history = [];`

You open your browser's empty frontpage and go to page1.html

now history is = `['page1.html']`.

If you fires pushState from page1.html with the url page2.html the history is now `['page1.html','page2.html']` and the address bar shows page2.html.

If the browser dosn't support pushState it does nothing. So for your example:

```
$("#close").live("click", function(event) {
    $("#board").slideUp("slow");
    window.history.pushState(null, null, site_url+"/");
    return false;
});
```

And when you load your ajax:

```
window.history.pushState(null,null,site_url + "/" + ajax_url);
```

---

If you want to operate with hash you can do something like this:

```
$("#close").live("click", function(event) {
    $("#board").slideUp("slow");
    window.location.href = "#/"
    return false;
});
```

And when you load your ajax:

```
window.location.href = "#/" + ajax_url
```

If you are using pushState be aware of the urls can end op pointing in subfolders you dont have and therefore you need some kind of .htaccess rewrite code

Comment: I would like my browser to change the url without reloading the page when I click on #close. The url I want is http://www.visualise.ca/ but it gives http://www.visualise.ca/#//

Comment: What about window.location.href = "" then?

Comment: It's all my fault... There was a type in my site_url variable ...! Sorry I made you lose your precious time :-(