# Swiper Slider url change on click image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please, anyone, give me solution for image URL change on click! I am using swiper for  image gallery

I am want to URL

http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/25-hash-navigation.html#slide2

to

http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/slide2

can you give me some solution, how i can do this...

Comment: do you have any idea how i can i change url on click with any slider

Comment: We need a little more info on your project rather than just 'slider'
do you have any code of attempts or anything to share?
btw localhost links will not work for us
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask/

Comment: example this website: [link](http://photogallery.indiatimes.com/celebs/celeb-themes/celebs-in-news/articleshow/53111550.cms) 

when you will change image this will change url...

Comment: Ooh then you're looking for *url rewriting*

Comment: I want to change link in swiper slider example
http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/25-hash-navigation.html#slide2

and after 

http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/id <=======

like

http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/slide2

Comment: yeah simply use the url rewrite link i gave you below and in the new url, apply the same url but remove the # with a string parser

Comment: hey can you me live example... please!

Answer (score 1):

Url-rewriting can be acheived by using the window object in javascript like so:

```
window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

Further reference on this : [Article on spoiledmilk.com](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/)

Comment: thank but i want to swiper slider image url on click

Comment: simply add an onclick event

Comment: I tried alot but not working.... even i saw this example [Example Site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008021/help-with-window-history-pushstate)

I need this in swiper slider... can you do this?